# Laravel 5.2: Class Imagick not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, imagick

We are converting PDF pages to multiple single images. We found a code snippet in stackoverflow and converted it to a service class. We have Imagick installed and it shows up in phpinfo() as well. However, in our laravel application, version 5.2, we are getting following error.

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 798:
Class Imagick does not exist
```

We tested our code outside laravel environment and it's working like a charm. No such error is thrown. We also ran following command to check Imagick

```
php -i | grep -i imagick
```

and this is the output

```
    /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
    imagick
    imagick module => enabled
    imagick module version => 3.4.3RC1
    imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
    Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-06-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-06-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
    imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
    imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
```

Everything seems right. It works outside Laravel but not in laravel. I got no idea what's wrong. Do we have to configure Laravel to use Imagick?

Here is our service class that we are using

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Utilities;

use Imagick;

class PdfToImageService
{
    /**
     * Destination folder where images will be saved
     * @var string
     */
    protected $destination = 'images/users/';

    /**
     * Injecting dependencies
     * 
     * @param Imagick $imagick
     */
    function __construct(Imagic $imagick)
    {
        $this->imagick = $imagick;
    }

    /**
     * Convert pdf having multiple pages to multiple single images
     * 
     * 1. Strip document extension
     * 2. Convert this document
     * 3. Set background color and flatten. It Prevents black background on objects with transparency
     * 4. Set image resolution
     * 5. Determine number of pages
     * 6. Compress Image Quality
     * 7. Generate images from each pdf page
     * 8. Destroy current imagick session
     * 
     * @param  string $fileName
     * @return array  $convertedImageNames
     */
    public function createImages($fileName)
    {
        $fileName = basename($fileName);
        $this->imagick->readImage($fileName);
        $this->imagick->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
        $this->imagick->setResolution(300,300);
        $this->imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(100);

        $convertedImageNames = $this->generateImageFromPDFPage(
            $fileName, $this->imagick->getNumberImages()
        );

        $this->imagick->destroy();

        return $convertedImageNames;
    }

    /**
     * Loop throught each pdf pages and convert it to image.
     *      A. Set iterator postion
     *      B. Set image format
     *      C. Write Images to destination folder 
     * 
     * @param  string  $fileName
     * @param  integer $noOfPages
     * @return array
     */
    private function generateImageFromPDFPage($fileName, $noOfPages)
    {
        for($i = 0;$i < $noOfPages; $i++) {
            $this->imagick->setIteratorIndex($i);
            $this->imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');    
            $this->imagick->writeImage($this->destination.$fileName.'-'.$i.'.jpg');
            $convertedImageNames[$i] = $fileName.'-'.$i.'.jpg';
        }

        return $convertedImageNames;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem might be namespace. Try adding \ in front of Imagick use statement. It might be Laravel resolving wrong class in IOC container, it might not be understanding the class in global namespace

Comment: did you try installing imagemagick ? 
`apt-get install imagemagick`

Comment: `function __construct(Imagic $imagick)` - that does not look like you try to load the correct class. Have you tried using `Imagick` instead of `Imagic`?

Answer (score 4):

### This is what worked for me for Laravel 5.7 on Homestead:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick php-imagick
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

If you're using a version of PHP other than 7.2 or aren't using Nginx, you'll need to adjust.

Comment: Package 'php-imagick' has no installation candidate

Comment: However, I found the answer here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/105#issuecomment-421081065

Answer (score 2):

Can you try editing php.ini located in 
**cd /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini** 
 if your linux is ubuntu ?

```
cat php.ini | grep extension=imagick.so
```

if there is the results of search, then you might get this 
**;extension=imagick.so** 
 You remove this semicolon ; 
and if not any results,

```
echo "extension=imagick.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

And finally

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apahce2 restart
```

It works with this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Imagick;

class GuestController extends BaseController {

    public $imagic;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->imagic = new Imagick();
    }

    public function test(){
        return get_class_methods($this->imagic);
    }
}
```

Comment: We already did that, adding the extension=imagick.so in  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restarting the apache server. We did all the required set up. I guess there is some issue with my laptop. It's working fine now. I should have restarted my laptop before. Anyway thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Dowload the extension here (the tarball): 
   http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

(Lets suppose you use the version: 3.4.3)

2. Go to the extension directory with the terminal
   Example

   ```
   cd /Downloads/
   ```
3. Extract the tarball

   ```
   tar xf imagick-3.4.3.tgz
   ```
4. Go to the new extracted directory

   ```
   cd imagick-3.4.3.tgz
   ```
5. Phpize the library (is base written in C)

   ```
   phpize
   ```
6. Run

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
7. Run

   ```
   make && make test && make install
   ```
8. Go to your php.ini (ussualy in Ubuntu located at /etc/php/7.x/cli/php.ini) and add this line:

   ```
   extension=imagick.so
   ```

That's it. Update php

```
    service php7.2-fpm restart
```

and the server (apache, nginx or other).

Comment: I get this error: "checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist"

Comment: Try if the extension is in php with phpinfo() http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: The `./configure` part. This worked for me though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742469/470749

Answer (score -1):

To install Imagick run bellow command:
`sudo apt-get install php-imagick`

For specific PHP version (in my case 7.1):
`sudo apt-get install php7.1-imagick`

Then restart apache:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

To check if the extension has been installed:
`php -m | grep imagick`

If the above approach doesn't works for you, try this:
`sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev`
`sudo apt-get install php-imagick`

Update php.ini with `extension=imagick.so` and then restart apache.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. According to the output of `php -i`, these packages are already installed