# Laravel 5.2, class 'Imagick' not found

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, homebrew, laravel-valet

I am using Laravel Valet. I have installed image magick and imagick via brew using the following commands

```
brew install imagemagick
```

and

```
brew install homebrew/php/php70-imagick
```

Inside my /project directory.

When I run brew search I get a little tick next to each, showing that they have installed.

However, when I try to use it in my project I get the dreaded "class Imagick not found" error. Not too sure what I did wrong here.

Comment: El Capitan, PHP 7.0.13

Comment: May be duplicate with -  [Laravel 5.2: Class Imagick not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833614/laravel-5-2-class-imagick-not-found)

Comment: No, its not a duplicate. That person was using apache server and my problem is with a Caddy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the extension to your php.ini:

```
echo "extension=imagick.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Restart Apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Or

Can you try editing php.ini located in

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

if your linux is ubuntu ?

```
cat php.ini | grep extension=imagick.so
```

if there is the results of search, then you might get this

```
;extension=imagick.so
You remove this semicolon ; and if not any results,
echo "extension=imagick.so" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

And finally

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apahce2 restart
```